# Show by substitution that: $\int^{xy}_{x}\frac{dt}{t}=\int^{y}_{1}\frac{dt}{t}$.

Tags: integration, analysis

probably it is an easy one, but I can't get my head around it.

Show by substitution that:
$$\int^{xy}_{x}\frac{dt}{t}=\int^{y}_{1}\frac{dt}{t}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let $u=t/x$ which implies $du=1/x\,dt$.

Comment: But  then $\int^{xy}_{x}\frac{dt}{t}=\int^{ty}_{t}\frac{dt}{t}$.

Comment: $t=x\implies u=1$, $t=xy\implies u=y$.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: In the integral. $t$ ranges from $x$ to $xy$.  So, $u=t/x$ ranges from $x/x$ to $xy/x$ or rather $1$ to $y$.

Comment: Remember: when you do $u$-substitution in a definite integral, you have to change the endpoints.  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleDefinite.aspx